# Why does makefile generate object files in current directory?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

This makefile generates `.o` files in `src/branch/` as well as in the top-level project directory containing the Makefile.

```
CXX := g++
SRC += $(wildcard src/file/*.cpp)
SRC += $(wildcard src/random/*.cpp)
SRC += $(wildcard src/termui/*.cpp)
SRC += $(wildcard src/graphics/*.cpp)
SRC += $(wildcard src/memory/*.cpp)
SRC += $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJ := $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
MAIN=ProcC
CXXFLAGS := -g -fPIC -std=c++11 -fpermissive
LIBS := -lboost_system -lboost_serialization -lboost_filesystem 

LIBDIR = -L ~/c/libraries/boost/lib -L ~/c/libraries/SFGUI-0.3.0/lib

INCDIR = -I include/ -I ~/c/libraries/boost/include/ 


.PHONY: depend clean

all:    $(MAIN)
    @echo Successfully compiled ProcC source code

$(MAIN): $(OBJ) 
    @echo Linking ProcC objects and dependencies into executable.
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCDIR) $(LIBDIR) -c $(SRC) $(LIBS)
    rm *.o

.cpp.o:
    @echo Compiling ProcC source code into objects.
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCDIR) -c $<  -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJ) 

depend: $(SRCS)
    makedepend $(INCDIR) $^
```

This makefile is supposed to generate objects from the source, but not an
executable; I intend to create `.so` files from this project as it is a library. Is there anything I am doing wrong in this makefile?

Comment: `all` is also `.PHONY`, `depend` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

> This makefile generates `.o` files in `src/branch/` as well as in the top-level project directory containing the Makefile.

This is because `.cpp.o:` rule produces the `.o` in the same directory as `.cpp`.

> This makefile is supposed to generate objects from the source, but not an executable

These rules:

```
all:    $(MAIN)
$(MAIN): $(OBJ) 
    @echo Linking ProcC objects and dependencies into executable.
```

build an executable with name `$(MAIN)` comprised of object files in `$(OBJ)`. If you do not want to build an executable, then do not build it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to build a shared library you have to change the ${MAIN} rule.
It currently uses CXX to compile (-c) all your SRC files. However, they were already compiled because the target depends on all OBJ. So in this rule you only need to link the shared library. You need to call CXX with -shared and OBJ instead of -c SRC.

However I would recommend you to try some modern build system like CMake 3.x which can significantly simplify your build scripts.

```
cmake_minimum_required(3.0)
project(ProcC)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_library(ProcC SHARED ... Source files here...)
target_include_directories( ProcC PUBLIC ... -I directories here... )
target_link_libraries(ProcC PUBLIC ... libraries here...)
```